# how to use a variable passed as a function argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

### UPDATE

I had a small typo , everything its working like it should.

I can't figure out how to use a variable passed as a function argument in an multiple ajax call as a selector.

First and Second are OK but when calling ThirdCallbackFunction clicking on the '"#button-" + id_number' doesn't trigger anything, although alert("#button-" + id_number) is showing the correct element #button-0 #button-1 ...etc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // FIRST
    $("#process").click(function(){
        var somedata = $("#somedata").val();
          $('input[type="text"]').removeClass("error");
          $.ajax({
              url: 'first.php',
              type: "POST",
              data: ({somedata: somedata }),
              beforeSend:function(){
                jQuery('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
              },
              success: function(data){
                  $("#ajax-panel").html(data);
                      SecondCallbackFunction();
              },
              error:function(){
                jQuery('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error">Oops!</p>');
              }
          }); 
        });
});
        // SECOND
        function SecondCallbackFunction(){
            $(".load-button").click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).closest('.box').attr('id');
                    var arr = id.split('-');
                    var id_number = arr[1];
                    alert(id_number);  //
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'second.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({id_number: id_number }),
                        beforeSend:function(){
                          $("#"+id).find('.load-button').hide();    
                          $("#"+id).append('<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#"+id).find('.loading').hide();  
                            $("#"+id).append(data);
                            ThirdCallbackFunction(id_number);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                          $("#"+id).append('<p class="error">Oops!</p>');
                        }
                    });

            });
        }
        // THIRD
        function ThirdCallbackFunction(id_number){
            alert(id_number);  // SHOWING 1 , 2 ....etc
            $("#button-" + id_number).bind("click", function() {   // DOING nothing
                    var title = $('#title' + id_number).val();              
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'third.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({title: title, 
                        }),
                        beforeSend:function(){
                           $("#item"+id_number).append('<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                             $("#item"+id_number).find('.loading').hide();  
                             $("#item"+id_number).append(data);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                          $("#"+id).append('<p class="error">Oops!</p>');
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your code apparently. Please post the HTML and Javascript needed to actually reproduce the problem, and keep only the relevant functions.

Comment: Anything in the console? When you do a `console.log` of the desired selector in `ThirdCallbackFunction` does it show there are any DOM elements that match? Does a `console.log` in the third click handler show up?

Comment: I had a small typo , everything its working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, but if you ever want to use any variables, objects, or anything that can be defined as a argument, simply wrap it as an array `[Variable]` (if not already,) get the function this variable will be passed to as an argument, and use the apply function. `func.apply(this, [Variable]);` If you happen to know the variables you want to pass, you can simply pass them normally:

```
(function() { })(variable1, variable2, /* ect... */);
```

Or use the call function:

```
func.call(this, variable1, variable2);
```

Where `func` is the function you're calling. You can also replace the keyword `this` with anything. If you do, any references to `this` inside the function will refer to the value you supplied. This is how frameworks such as jQuery allow you to access the jQuery object by referring to `this` inside their framework.